# SQL Query and Unicode Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unicode, collation

I have a really weird issue with Sql queries on unicode data. Here's what I've got:

- Sql Server Express 2008 R2 AS
- Table containing chinese characters/words/phrases (100,000 rows)

When I run the following, I get the correct row + 36 other rows returned... when it should only be the one row:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [ID]
      ,[MyChineseColumn]
      ,UNICODE([MyChineseColumn])
  FROM [dbo].[MyTableName]
  WHERE [MyChineseColumn]= N'㐅'
```

As you'd expect, the row with `㐅` is returned, but also the following: `〇`, `宁`, `㮸` and a bunch of others...

Anyone have any ideas what is going on here? This has really got me confused and I am not sure how to solve this one (tried "Googling" already)...

Thanks

Comment: I should also mention that most of the other rows are all querying perfectly fine...it's only a handful of "dodgy" ones like the above that I'd really like to figure out the reason for. Maybe it's a certain range of Unicode characters that are doing this? I haven't got a clue...

Comment: Since I don't have a font that can display 㐅 or 㐅, they look identical to me. Just as a info: the first (and second) 㐅 is [U+3405 CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-3405](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3405/index.htm), while the second one (the last character in the list of wrong results) is [U+3BB8 CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-3BB8](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3BB8/index.htm).

Comment: What is your column collation?

Comment: Thank you Martin... I did some research and found the collation I needed to use and it's working now. I'd like to mark this as the answer, but you've only commented. If you add it as an answer, I will mark it "ANSWERED" for you.  :-)   Thanks!

Comment: @Matt - Done! Just out of curiosity what collation were you using that treated those 4 characters all the same? Even under `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI` I got 2 rows back for `declare @t TABLE (c nchar(1) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI) INSERT INTO @t values (N'㐅'),(N'〇'),(N'宁'),(N'㮸') SELECT DISTINCT c FROM @t`

Comment: Hi Martin,I was using Latin1_General_CI_AS (DB Default). Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the column is using an appropriate Chinese collation as that will determine the semantics used in this type of comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try and use a binary collation, these characters seem to be somehow matched as identical (possibly by ignoring case and/or accents, depending on the used collation).