# SQL query returns wrong result because of ä

Tags: c#, database

I have an item in db with this content:

```
B &amp; b / v (st&auml;rrfood) - 1,0l
```

And this:

```
var item = (from x in db.tblMyTable where x.item_name == "B & b / v (stärrfood) - 1,0l" select x).First();
```

returns that there is no such item. I think it's because of the ä. What to do?

Comment: If your retrieving an item by name, I'm guessing it's a constant in your system.  Is it possible to retrieve the item via ID/PK instead?

Comment: @rie819 I'm retrieving it by name here, to simplify my question.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887447/sql-query-and-unicode-issue

Comment: What does SQL Profiler show as the T-SQL query being sent to the server?

Comment: this code is similar to your code, and it's working fine..
string[] arr = { "B & b / v (stärrfood) - 1,0l", "a", "b" };
        var res = (from item in arr where item =="B & b / v (stärrfood) - 1,0l" select item).First().ToString();
        Response.Write(res);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your DB item actually reads

```
B &amp; b / v (st&auml;rrfood) - 1,0l
```

and not

```
B & b / v (stärrfood) - 1,0l
```

then the problem is clear; the strings inside your DB have been HtmlEncoded. So the actual question is how to get from the second string, to the first.

Usually I would recommend:

```
string encoded = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("B & b / v (stärrfood) - 1,0l");
// encoded = "B &amp; b / v (st&#228;rrfood) - 1,0l"
```

and searching for the encoded variable instead. However, the result of `HtmlEncode()` is close but not exactly equal to your DB record. The `HtmlEncode()` uses the numeric entities instead of the alphabetic version.

But this might give you a clue as to how to solve the problem. Still I'd highly recommend not searching for string but using a numeric PK value instead. This problem can be quite difficult to solve I think.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your query and then see what actually comes back.

For instance, you may look for all records that *contain* "ä". If you get results, the "ä" is not the problem.

If you don't get results, you may look for all records that contain "B & b / v".

Either way, when you get a result back, see what is in that result and how it is encoded (is it ASCII, UTF-8, ...?) Then you'll know how to modify your query to get the right record back.

Good luck!

Comment: The ä is problem like '%ä%' returns no results.